# Why do I get this error?: Expected singleton: spray.action(1, 2)

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo, odoo-view

I have a button in a form that when clicked is supposed to update the current model `mrl` with data from the `spray.action` model. Then I do further processing but it raises the error

```
ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self) ValueError: Expected singleton: spray.action(1, 2)
```

```py
@api.multi
def mrlCreateSprayRecords(self):
    spray_ids = []
    vals = []
    spray_obj = self.env['spray.action'].search([])
    print("spray_obj  \n\n\n\t %s ", spray_obj)
    for obj in spray_obj:
        print("Spray Action Objects  \n\n %s \n\t ", obj)
        vals = {
            'ref': obj.ref,
            'farm': obj.farm.farm,
            'block': obj.block.block,
            'valves': obj.valves.valve,
        }
        print("Spray Action Data Browse , \n\n\t %s ", vals)
        res = super(Mrl, self).create(vals)
        res.update(vals)
        print("object in mrlCreateSprayRecords \n\n\t  %s", res)
    return {
        'name': 'Update Mrl Operations',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'mrl',
        'views': [(spray_obj.id, 'form')],
        'view_id': spray_obj.id,
        # 'target': 'new',
        'res_id': self.id,
        'context': self.env.context,

    }
```

Comment: Next time try to ask with less noise to help the readers to answer, please :P

Comment: Just add limit=1 in your search, eg. spray_obj = self.env['spray.action'].search([], limit=1)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are getting the error in the row `'view_id': spray_obj.id,` you must write the view id there. The `spray_obj` recordset has many record, so you cannot use it like that (`spray_obj.id`). You can also remove the `view_id` parameter in order to user the default view.

```py
@api.multi
def mrlCreateSprayRecords(self):
    self.ensure_one()

    spray_obj = self.env['spray.action'].search([])     # recordset of all records of the model????
    for obj in spray_obj:
        vals = {
            'ref': obj.ref,
            'farm': obj.farm.farm,
            'block': obj.block.block,
            'valves': obj.valves.valve,
        }
        self.create(vals)

    view_id = self.env.ref('module.xml_view_id').id         

    return {
        'name': 'Update Mrl Operations',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'mrl',
        'view_id': view_id,
        'res_id': self.id,
        'context': self.env.context,
    }
```

I have added `self.ensure_one()` because `res_id` has to be only one id as well.

I have remove the `res.update(vals)` line because it does not make any sense to me haha

**More things**

Instead of print you should use the logger:

```py
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

_logger.info('Hello')
```

Instead the line `res = super(Mrl, self).create(vals)` I think you should use this one

```py
res = self.create(vals)     # if you are in the mrl model
```

Answer (score 2):

In short you get this kind of error when you acces a field direclty of a recordSet that contains more than one record.

You performed a search on the spray.action that search returnd 2 record `(1, 2)`

So when you do `spray_obj.id` odoo will be confused what id he should return 1 or 2. And here odoo throw this error.

So dont access a field a search result,  or a x2many fiels they may have more than one record inside.

@ChesuCR has improved your code and corrected it